# Using Regular Expressions for Verilog Port Mapping

Tags: regex, verilog

I have a really long port map where I want to replace a bunch of

```
SignalName[i],
```

with

```
.SignalName(SignalName[i]),
```

I think I can do this easily with regular expressions, but I can't for the life of me figure out how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming SignalData is the file containing your port map information, the following would do what you want.

```
sed -si 's/\([a-zA-Z]\+\)\(\[[^\]]*\]\)/\.\1(\1\2)/g' SignalData
```

In sed s stands for substitution, regex between the first pair of // is used to match against each line. If a match is found the expression between upto the next / is made to replace what was matched.

Explanation of regex

```
\([a-zA-Z]\+\) - Matches a series of alphabets (like SignalName) and captures it into
\1. If you want only the SignalName string to match, replace [a-zA-Z]\+ with SignalName.
\(\[[^\]]*\]\) - Matches the [some character] part and captures it into \2
```

Finally we use these captured strings to construct the desired string.

If you want to experiment with this before running on your file use sed -s instead of sed -si. That will show the results of the transformation on stdout, without actually changing the file

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in 3 years late, but I highly recommend verilog mode for emacs.  It simplifies this kind of operation for instantiating modules.  For example, if you have a module like this:

```
module submodule(
  input [1:0] ina,
  input inb,
  input inc,
  output outa);

  /*some stuff*/

endmodule
```

You can instantiate this using verilog mode:

```
module mymodule(
  /*AUTOOUTPUT*/
  /*AUTOINPUT*/);

  submodule submod(/*AUTOINST*/);

endmodule
```

When you expand AUTOs in emacs (C-c C-a), you get this:

```
module mymodule(
  input [1:0] ina,
  input inb,
  input inc,
  output outa);

  submodule submod(
    .ina    (ina),
    .inb    (inb),
    .inc    (inc),
    .outa   (outa));

endmodule
```

You can expand this with simplified regular expressions and lisp equations to do complex connections.  Saves a ton of time when wiring together a bunch of modules or changing signal names through the hierarchy.

Much more info here:
http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode/Verilog-mode_veritedium