# How to remove I/O port declarations using regexp in verilog mode

Tags: emacs, verilog

I'm trying to instantiate `abc_d` module and i don't want all of its ports to be declared as I/O ports in `abc` top module. I want to exclude `ex_out_port` to be declared as `output` port.

```
module abc(/*AUTOARG*/);
/*AUTOINPUT*/
/*AUTOOUTPUT*/
/*AUTOWIRE*/
abc_d u_abc_d(/*AUTOINST*/);
endmodule
//Localvariables:
//verilog-auto-output-ignore-regexp:("ex_out_port")
//END:
```

expected code:

```
 module abc (/*AUTOARG*/
 /Inputs
 input port1;
 input port2;
 /Outputs
 output port3;
 output port4;
 /*AUTOWIRE*/
 wire ex_out_port;

 //Instance
 abc_d u_abc_d(/*AUTOINST*/
 .port1 (port1),
 .port2 (port2),
 .port3 (port3),
 .port4 (port4),
 .ex_out_port (ex_out_port)):
endmodule
```

Related already-answered questions:

- [Using Regular Expressions for Verilog Port Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2653055)
- [using emacs auto's to instansiate a stub module (inputs=0, outputs=[]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31184100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `verilog-auto-output-ignore-regexp` is slightly off. It works after dropping the parenthesis around "ex_out_port"

```
//verilog-auto-output-ignore-regexp: "ex_out_port"
```

I was not able to find any code examples gnore-regexp in documentation or FAQ. I did find one example in a forum on the veriloop site (owners of verilog-mode): 
https://www.veripool.org/boards/15/topics/1635-Verilog-mode-Scope-for-AUTO_LISP-

---

FYI: Unless you are strictly following Verilog-1995 syntax or running obsolete version of verilog-mode, you can consider change:

```
module abc(/*AUTOARG*/);
/*AUTOINPUT*/
/*AUTOOUTPUT*/
/*AUTOWIRE*/
```

To an ANSI style header which is supported since Verilog-2001:

```
module abc(
/*AUTOINPUT*/
/*AUTOOUTPUT*/
);
/*AUTOWIRE*/
```

It is functionally and behaviorally the same with fewer lines of generated code.